# mutt: garbage characters in mail titles

Tags: mutt

I compiled [Mutt](http://www.mutt.org/) from the source. When I connect to my IMAP mailbox, some mails (but not all) have incorrect titles:

```
21   F 10/19 To Someone      (0.4K)     M-b~T~LM-b~T~@>
22 r + 10/19 Someone         (1.0K)   M-b~T~LM-b~T~@>
23   F 10/19 To Someone      (0.2K) M-b~T~LM-b~T~@>
```

The mutt version and compilation options:

```
Mutt 1.5.21 (2010-09-15)

System: Linux 3.2.0-30-generic-pae (i686)
ncurses: ncurses 5.9.20110404 (compiled with 5.9)
hcache backend: Berkeley DB 4.8.30: (April  9, 2010)
Compile options:
-DOMAIN
-DEBUG
-HOMESPOOL  +USE_SETGID  +USE_DOTLOCK  +DL_STANDALONE  +USE_FCNTL  -USE_FLOCK
-USE_POP  +USE_IMAP  -USE_SMTP
+USE_SSL_OPENSSL  -USE_SSL_GNUTLS  -USE_SASL  -USE_GSS  +HAVE_GETADDRINFO
+HAVE_REGCOMP  -USE_GNU_REGEX
+HAVE_COLOR  +HAVE_START_COLOR  +HAVE_TYPEAHEAD  +HAVE_BKGDSET
+HAVE_CURS_SET  +HAVE_META  +HAVE_RESIZETERM
+CRYPT_BACKEND_CLASSIC_PGP  +CRYPT_BACKEND_CLASSIC_SMIME  -CRYPT_BACKEND_GPGME
-EXACT_ADDRESS  -SUN_ATTACHMENT
+ENABLE_NLS  -LOCALES_HACK  +HAVE_WC_FUNCS  +HAVE_LANGINFO_CODESET  +HAVE_LANGINFO_YESEXPR
+HAVE_ICONV  -ICONV_NONTRANS  -HAVE_LIBIDN  +HAVE_GETSID  +USE_HCACHE
-ISPELL
SENDMAIL="/usr/sbin/sendmail"
MAILPATH="/var/mail"
PKGDATADIR="/usr/local/share/mutt"
SYSCONFDIR="/usr/local/etc"
EXECSHELL="/bin/sh"
-MIXMASTER
```

Comment: Those aren't the subject lines - `mutt` is using what it thinks are line-drawing characters to draw a message thread tree, but there's a mismatch between what `mutt` thinks are the right characters to use and what your terminal will accept as line-drawing characters; your terminal is displaying them as combinations of meta- and control-characters instead. You'll have to play with your locale settings and/or terminal options and/or `mutt` options to find a reasonable combination that looks right...

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer here: http://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/MuttFaq/Charset

Basically what went wrong was linking against the wrong ncurses library. What you want is linking against `libncursesw`:

```
$ ldd `which mutt` | grep curses
libncursesw.so.5 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5 (0xb7752000)
```

not just `libncurses`. Checking at my configure script, the output was similar to this:

```
checking for ncurses/ncurses.h... no
checking for waddnwstr in -lncursesw... no
```

After installing `libncursesw5-dev` (Ubuntu/Debian), the correct libraries were found, linked against and the headers look fine.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem with Putty when trying to use mutt through SSH. The solution is to change the charset used.

Putty->Settings->Window->Translation

Changed charset form ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) to UTF-8.

Incidentally, the same page also has settings for how Putty handles line-drawing characters, but this didn't do anything for me.